# How do I find records matching attribute with 1+ values in ActiveRecord/SQL?

Tags: sql, activerecord

How do I find records matching attribute with 1+ values in ActiveRecord/SQL?  Examples would be something like:

```
Post.find_by_type("Post and/or ChildPost")
Post.find(:type => "Post and/or ChildPost")
```

How can I do this?  The number of values will be no more than 10 I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post.find :all, :conditions => ['type IN (?)', ['Post', 'ChildPost']]
```

Or:

```
values = ['Post', 'ChildPost']
Post.find :all, :conditions => ['type IN (?)', values]
```

That should produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `type` IN ('Post', 'ChildPost');
```